# HTTP error 400 on google_elevation() call

Tags: r, google-maps, r-package, googleway

I am using the R-package googleway to decode polylines using `decode_pl`and subsequently getting the elevation data at the corresponding lat/lon coordinates using `google_elevation`. I get the polylines from [Strava](http://www.strava.com), using the [rStrava](https://github.com/fawda123/rStrava) package.

Sample polylines:

```
pl1 <- "q{|aHknlv@n@Mt@IxAGb@B\\Eb@AZGRG^W`AyAPQF?NHDJFZBz@FVNPn@D`@C|@DjACv@@h@Dh@Ll@Zj@^\\`@fAx@j@r@d@n@\\ZJPNd@NbANzAFhANb@JNLHD?PKHMRGPSr@UPMXGDGJELMFCPAbBWROpAm@h@YZe@dAaC@Of@aAb@a@t@iALg@LWNQROf@IjAJnFbAv@Dr@Aj@BpBx@fFdCd@HlAHd@Pp@b@|@d@~@j@n@R~@n@\\NTCXBNEZCZKbB]rAKpDK~BO\\?NCd@?`DMz@SLO`@URCR@XLRRRVHd@NXNP\\RXf@JHXN\\Xn@ZD@Z?\\NvArA~BxA"
pl2 <- "uipaHmmcv@iBoFm@{AKQy@}B}AoDyA_CASEMGKKI]y@i@y@EOi@q@kAw@KEMAu@M]?[@WDkAZiB~@]H_@PUF]TUL_@XkAn@}CzAyAx@e@P_@JSNGROPa@Fu@[UOc@IOAu@_@WIUMIIWGu@]YEk@SoBiAc@_@gAeAg@{@]mAMq@YmBA]Oq@YuBKYUg@UQa@QiAOI@QIm@EiA[w@BSFYZ_@h@]t@o@bAOb@}@zAWn@_@jAGf@SbAKbAKXSpAS`@ICa@FSHICQ@gAHq@KSAa@I[CQ@k@KOGMKYg@aBkEs@u@k@g@_@a@{@o@W]IAYQYAsDIODc@LW\\GRKn@Ch@WtAO`BCzAIj@Wh@SRc@NS@a@KaAg@kCgAm@]iBo@w@_@UQc@S}@Ww@e@MCa@Sm@Sk@WYI{@g@IIMAMIIIm@QuBaAIGu@_@SQiAqA_AmASSYIUEqAKQBm@Im@Qe@i@k@UQBSCe@NO?[FKFYBSH_ADa@GQIw@OOSKF[b@M@gAl@i@b@{@b@OLwAj@KLWRI@yBvAuAd@m@F_@@qAEk@Kc@Oi@_@_@e@oAeBc@u@SSi@]i@We@Im@Q}@k@w@_@i@a@w@a@SQ[Qy@OeCSUGg@WSOa@e@W]MK_@i@CMMWIEMWa@m@[QEIICK@QHUTe@n@ELKFa@l@u@t@WNYLYXO?IBGHc@Tc@Ja@@{@Q{@]s@a@kBq@YOcAYs@IU?_@NU@GAu@^a@LSPg@X]^YJc@h@]PKHI@w@n@]h@AXEJMTCZc@|AS`@OVg@j@_Av@{@bA"
```

Decoding works fine:

```
decoded_pl1 <- decode_pl(pl1)
decoded_pl2 <- decode_pl(pl2)
```

But when I try to get the elevation, I get an error on the second polyline, and I can't make real sense of it:

```
# This one works fine
google_elevation(decode_pl(pl1), key=gmap_key)

# This one gives HTTP error 400
google_elevation(decode_pl(pl2), key=gmap_key)
```

I checked the lat/lon data coming out of the `decode_pl` and they seems fine. I can't really make sense of it...

I make this exact same call on a whole set of coordinates, and this is the only one that errors.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a fix to the development version of `googleway`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update 14/03/2017

I've issued a [fix to the development version](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/commit/34ae0d326a076be34dcb86d327ca24cefbd022ac) so that `google_elevation()` now accepts an encoded polyline as an argument. And it will also issue a warning if the URL length is greater than 8192 characters.

```
## install the development version
devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")
library(googleway)

api_key <- "your_api_key"
map_key <- "your_map_key" ## for plotting the lines

pl1 <- "q{|aHknlv@n@Mt@IxAGb@B\\Eb@AZGRG^W`AyAPQF?NHDJFZBz@FVNPn@D`@C|@DjACv@@h@Dh@Ll@Zj@^\\`@fAx@j@r@d@n@\\ZJPNd@NbANzAFhANb@JNLHD?PKHMRGPSr@UPMXGDGJELMFCPAbBWROpAm@h@YZe@dAaC@Of@aAb@a@t@iALg@LWNQROf@IjAJnFbAv@Dr@Aj@BpBx@fFdCd@HlAHd@Pp@b@|@d@~@j@n@R~@n@\\NTCXBNEZCZKbB]rAKpDK~BO\\?NCd@?`DMz@SLO`@URCR@XLRRRVHd@NXNP\\RXf@JHXN\\Xn@ZD@Z?\\NvArA~BxA"
pl2 <- "uipaHmmcv@iBoFm@{AKQy@}B}AoDyA_CASEMGKKI]y@i@y@EOi@q@kAw@KEMAu@M]?[@WDkAZiB~@]H_@PUF]TUL_@XkAn@}CzAyAx@e@P_@JSNGROPa@Fu@[UOc@IOAu@_@WIUMIIWGu@]YEk@SoBiAc@_@gAeAg@{@]mAMq@YmBA]Oq@YuBKYUg@UQa@QiAOI@QIm@EiA[w@BSFYZ_@h@]t@o@bAOb@}@zAWn@_@jAGf@SbAKbAKXSpAS`@ICa@FSHICQ@gAHq@KSAa@I[CQ@k@KOGMKYg@aBkEs@u@k@g@_@a@{@o@W]IAYQYAsDIODc@LW\\GRKn@Ch@WtAO`BCzAIj@Wh@SRc@NS@a@KaAg@kCgAm@]iBo@w@_@UQc@S}@Ww@e@MCa@Sm@Sk@WYI{@g@IIMAMIIIm@QuBaAIGu@_@SQiAqA_AmASSYIUEqAKQBm@Im@Qe@i@k@UQBSCe@NO?[FKFYBSH_ADa@GQIw@OOSKF[b@M@gAl@i@b@{@b@OLwAj@KLWRI@yBvAuAd@m@F_@@qAEk@Kc@Oi@_@_@e@oAeBc@u@SSi@]i@We@Im@Q}@k@w@_@i@a@w@a@SQ[Qy@OeCSUGg@WSOa@e@W]MK_@i@CMMWIEMWa@m@[QEIICK@QHUTe@n@ELKFa@l@u@t@WNYLYXO?IBGHc@Tc@Ja@@{@Q{@]s@a@kBq@YOcAYs@IU?_@NU@GAu@^a@LSPg@X]^YJc@h@]PKHI@w@n@]h@AXEJMTCZc@|AS`@OVg@j@_Av@{@bA"


df_elevation <- google_elevation(polyline = pl2, key = api_key)

head(df_elevation$results)
# elevation location.lat location.lng resolution
# 1  418.8341     47.60235      9.03399    19.0879
# 2  420.8099     47.60288      9.03519    19.0879
# 3  421.0847     47.60311      9.03565    19.0879
# 4  421.1900     47.60317      9.03574    19.0879
# 5  422.5887     47.60346      9.03637    19.0879
# 6  445.3051     47.60393      9.03725    19.0879
```

And seeing as we're on the development version we can plot the lines on a google map

```
df <- data.frame(pl = c(pl1, pl2))

google_map(key = map_key) %>%
    add_polylines(data = df, polyline = "pl")
```

[image]

---

### Old answer

You have inadvertently found the limits of the amount of data you can pass into the API

The [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro) says

> You may pass any number of multiple coordinates within an array or encoded polyline, as long as you don't exceed the service quotas, while still constructing a valid URL

So it seems you've found that limit.

If you reduce the amount of lat/lons you send from the second polyline you get results returned. In your example, the limit is 239 pairs of coordinates.

```
# head(google_elevation(decode_pl(pl2)[1:239,], key=gmap_key)$results)
# elevation location.lat location.lng resolution
# 1  418.8218     47.60235     9.033990    19.0879
# 2  420.8087     47.60288     9.035190    19.0879
# 3  421.0829     47.60311     9.035649    19.0879
# 4  421.1866     47.60317     9.035740    19.0879
# 5  422.5816     47.60346     9.036369    19.0879
# 6  445.2881     47.60393     9.037250    19.0879


google_elevation(decode_pl(pl2)[1:240,], key=gmap_key)
# Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400.
```

I've [filed this as an issue](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/35) so that in the next update this will be handled with either a more helpful error, or it will automatically break up the `data.frame`.

For now the solution will be to decode the polylines first, then find the elevation on subsets of the data.frame at a time.

---

I've gone back to the [Google Elevation API documentaition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro) and it appears you can also send an encoded polyline to the API; if you can wait a few days I'll issue a fix to the development version so you can send the polyline directly

---

disclaimer: I'm the googleway author

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift answer. I posted here, because I saw you answer questions regarding googleway directly. :-) I have for now removed the entry from my list of polylines and can add it back later, as I am only working on a proof of concept at this stage anyway. Thank you. Question answered!

Comment: One more question, should I find a bug like this again, shall I open an issue on your github?

Comment: @FranzHahn Personally I don't mind as there are benefits to both; I get emailed about github posts so I'll see that sooner, but on here you'll get wider exposure so more people could answer / benefit from the post.