# Lexical Error using Googleway in R

Tags: r, google-maps, googleway

I have approx 900 lat long pairings which I wish to get the associated elevation data for.

Within R there is a package called Googleway for querying the Google Maps API.

I've installed the package and called the library within R. I've also requested an API key which I tested and confirmed it's working.

Within R I've created a data frame `DF` which looks as follows:

```
> head(DF,10)
        lat       lon
1  52.69373 -8.609117
2  52.69910 -8.832892
3  52.69224 -8.919400
4  52.85152 -8.983660
5  52.74925 -8.911150
6  52.78698 -9.164880
7  52.99315 -9.371800
8  52.68393 -9.646870
9  52.84660 -8.979998
10 52.70877 -9.315228
```

My data frame consists of only two columns lat and lon as per the instructions in the Googleway help info.

I've subsequently written the following code but I am getting a "lexical error" as follows:

```
> result <- google_elevation(df_locations = DF, key = "somekeygoeshere")
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       https://maps.googleapis.com/map
                     (right here) ------^
```

I'm unsure as to what the error is referring to, is this something internal within the Googleway library or is there an error with my data? And "somekeygoeshere" is where I've entered my API key.

Comment: With the 10 rows of data you've supplied, I don't get the error. Are you able to narrow it down to a sub-set of the data that causes the error?

Comment: @SymbolixAU, just as I posted the question I tried with a single coor pair and it worked, then increased it to 10, that worked also, increased it to 40 that worked too and then used the original 954 and I got the same error. Is there a limit with get requests or message sizes that can be sent to Google Maps API? BTW thanks for the fantastic tool!!

Comment: Funnily enough, [this question identified and found the limit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42746432/5977215) a few days ago.

Comment: If you install the development version of the package, you can use `encode_pl()` to encode your coordinates into a polyline. If it's less than 8192 characters you may be able to use that.