# Replacing every second comma in the string in R

Tags: r, regex, google-maps-api-3

I have a string representing lat, long coordinates that is displayed like this:

```
30.538358,-96.692008,30.538602,-96.691741,30.539737,-96.690322
```

I need to replace every second comma with a `|`

```
30.538358,-96.692008|30.538602,-96.691741|30.539737,-96.690322
```

I need this because the Google MAPS elevation service needs this format.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `gsub` and a regular expression.

```
string = "30.538358,-96.692008,30.538602,-96.691741,30.539737,-96.690322"
gsub("([^,]+,[^,]+),", "\\1|", string)
"30.538358,-96.692008|30.538602,-96.691741|30.539737,-96.690322"
```

Answer (score 0):

In R you can use the `google_elevation()` function from my `googleway` package to call Google's Elevation API

```
df <- read.table(text = "lat,lon
                 30.538358,-96.692008
                 30.538602,-96.691741
                 30.539737,-96.690322",header=T,sep = ",")

google_elevation(df_locations = df, key = apiKey)
# $results
# elevation location.lat location.lng resolution
# 1  101.8991     30.53836    -96.69201   9.543952
# 2  102.0905     30.53860    -96.69174   9.543952
# 3  101.2652     30.53974    -96.69032   9.543952
# 
# $status
# [1] "OK"
```

Or if you have more points it's better to encode them into a polyline so that you don't reach the API query limit [as found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746432/http-error-400-on-google-elevation-call).

To use this approach you need the development version of the package

```
## devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")
## library(googleway)
pl <- encode_pl(lat = df$lat, lon = df$lon)
pl
# "uokyD~cdmQq@s@aF{G"
google_elevation(polyline = pl, key = apiKey)
# $results
# elevation location.lat location.lng resolution
# 1  101.9124     30.53835    -96.69200   9.543952
# 2  102.0864     30.53860    -96.69174   9.543952
# 3  101.1588     30.53973    -96.69032   9.543952
# 
# $status
# [1] "OK"
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the googleway package. This will surely help me.