# Error quests for Google Map Elevation API

Tags: r, google-maps, google-elevation-api

I am writing a R script to crawl evelatio for a large number of GPS points, using XML and RCurl package.
With the help of [Google Map Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro), it's useful to get the evelation value.
Here I notice that the [maximum number of locations in a request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/usage-limits) is 512.
The script works fine when there are like 100 GPS points in a requests. So I tried to get 512 elevation values at a request, as I have too many GPS poins.

However, the scrip returns an error saying

> Failed to connect to maps.googleapis.com port 443: Timed out

And when I type the url of the request with 512 GPS locations in Chrome, there is also an error, saying

> error 413 request entity too large

Did I  misunderstand what Google says for the limit of this API? Or does anyone know whats the problem? And how to solve that?

Comment: How are you building your request?

Comment: @geocodezip  As mentioned on [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro), this is my request <https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/xml?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034|36.455556,-116.866667|...&key=my key here>

Comment: And I just tried again and found that the max locations in a request is only 270

Comment: as you're using `r`, have you tried my `googleway` package, and the `google_elevation()` function?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. And good to know the package`googleway`. I fixed my problem by reducing the number of locations in a request to 250 and system pause if no data returned for a request. For guys who may encounter the same problem, even in the function `google_elevation`, you can not give 512 locations in one request. So be careful! @SymbolixAU

Comment: @KaiXie - yes, I [found that out here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42746432/5977215) - thanks for the warning. Also, if your points follow a path, you can encode them into a polyline, which will allow you to send more coordinates through at a time.

Comment: @SymbolixAU thank you bro. The `googleway` package is really helpful in terms of running speed, compared with mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error fixed by reducing the number of locations in a request and setting system pause for request error. Though it costs some time, it's fine for my case. For guy who have millions of GPS points, I think it's still a problem...